# Portable Internationalization

Tags: flutter

Assume that you have a complex preexisting app with thousands of strings and having multiple translations already in place using the android Strings.xml approach.   What would be the smartest way to port this work to a Flutter rewrite of the same app?  In addition, what would be the smartest way to share this internationalization approach with any Android Java code that is not portable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a correct answer. Give a good read over [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post with a specific problem you have - ideally presenting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to replicate it.